# The [weak self] is giving an error for the following code: Expected ',' Separator

Tags: ios, swift3

```
fileprivate func hideViewWithAnimation() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self]  
        if self == nil {
            return
        }

        self!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

        self!.constraintContainerViewBottom.constant = -Constants.screenHeight()
        self!.constraintContainerViewTop.constant = Constants.screenHeight()
        self!.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { (isCompleted) in
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }) 
}
```

There is an error showing for [weak self] asking to separate it using ','. What am i doing wrong

Comment: `[weak self] in`, you dont have `in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tj3n said, when you use the `[weak self]` syntax, you need the `in` keyword, e.g.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
    self?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

    ...
}
```

But you don't need `[weak self]` in animation block at all, because the animation block does not keep a strong reference to `self` for the duration of the animation. There is no strong reference cycle to break. So I'd suggest removing the `[weak self]` altogether.

And, in case you're wondering, you don't need to worry about strong references in the `completion` block, either, because when the view is dismissed, animations underway are cancelled and the `completion` block is immediately called with `false` for the boolean parameter.

Comment: Thanks. i figured it out later that we don't need [weak self] for animations block.'

Answer (score -3):

```
private func hideViewWithAnimation() {

    weak var weakSelf = self

    if weakSelf != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

            self!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

            self!.constraintContainerViewBottom.constant = -Constants.screenHeight()
            self!.constraintContainerViewTop.constant = Constants.screenHeight()
            self!.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (isCompleted) in
            self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        }

    }
}
```